# Removal of drain extension pipe at the wall under bathroom sink

Tags: plumbing

I'm replacing the drain pipes under my bathroom sink and having trouble removing the final section behind the escutcheon that connect to the wall fitting. I have a metal pipe extension pushed into a brass nipple fitting at the wall. The extension is  trapped in the brass nipple via a washer that is internal to the brass nipple so I cannot pull it out without removing the brass nipple. The nipple has a hex nut but it's inset in the wall behind the tiles. I cannot turn it without removing tiles and causing wall damage. What to do? 
Photo links:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1th3h.jpg
[image: https://i.imgur.com/KDQ1PRD.jpg]

[image]

Comment: Post your pic on imgur.com, then add the link/filepath in a comment to your question. One of us will post it to your question. When you have a bit more cred, you will be able to ad pictures directly to your post via imgur.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/NmUOyOz.jpg
https://i.imgur.com/KDQ1PRD.jpg

Comment: That is an unconventional assembly! Was there a nut screwed to those threads or was it just like that?

Comment: Yes, there's a nut. I've included a photo of it here: https://i.imgur.com/QM0NDw1.jpg

Comment: Have you tried twisting and pulling with a fair amount of force? That type of connection is usually a *slip-joint* fitting and can be pulled directly apart. The presence of the brass ring is pecuiliar, however; usually a rubber slip-joint washer would be found there.

Answer (score 1):

Cut the extension pipe off close with a hacksaw.

Then use a regular socket on the brass nut.

Answer (score 0):

You could always cut into the wall just enough to do your work and then put a larger  cover around the pipe to hide your mess. I'd find the cover first before cutting the wall so that you know for sure how much you can cut.